# Function to get duplicates info for given column names

Tags: function, powerbi, duplicates, powerquery

I need a function in PowerQuery to get additional columns for duplicated data (not just keep/remove duplicates).

**Example**:

[image]

For the given table, I want to get the following info for duplicated columns set `{"Date", "Product", "Color"}`:

1. `DuplInfo.MinRowId` - basically, Id of the first occurrence of data
2. `DuplInfo.nDupl` - duplicates counter within MinRowId group

NB! For non duplicates it should return `null` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following function ([download](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/main/Questions/DetailsColumns4Duplicates.pbix)):

Function call Example:

```
tfnAddDuplicatesInfo2(Source,{"Product","Color","Date"},"DuplInfo" ,"RowId")
```

---

Function Arguments:

```
         srcTable    as           table, // input Table
         inGroupBy   as           list,  // List of ColumnNames to search duplicates 
         outDuplInfo as           text,  // Output ColumnName for Information about Duplicates - Duplicate number and Minimal RowId (if inRowId provided) within a group
optional inRowId     as nullable  text   // RowId ColumnName - required for outMinRowId calculation for inGroupBy columns
```

---

Function body:

```
let 
    func = (
                 srcTable    as           table, // input Table
                 inGroupBy   as           list,  // List of ColumnNames to search duplicates 
                 outDuplInfo as           text,  // Output ColumnName for Information about Duplicates - Duplicate number and Minimal RowId (if inRowId provided) within a group
        optional inRowId     as nullable  text   // RowId ColumnName - required for outMinRowId calculation for inGroupBy columns
    ) =>
    let 
        Source = srcTable,
            
        // // To test as script
        // inGroupBy        = {"Product", "Color","Date"},
        // outDuplInfo      = "DuplInfo",        
        // inRowId          = "RowId", // null, "RowId",      
        
        //> == Variables ===================================================
        Columns2Expand = List.Combine({List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),inGroupBy),{"__outDuplCounter__"}}),
        srcType    = Value.Type(Source),       
        srcTypeRow= 
            Type.ForRecord(
                Record.Combine( 
                    {
                        Type.RecordFields(Type.TableRow(srcType)),
                        Type.RecordFields(type [__outDuplCounter__= Int64.Type])
                    }
                ),
                false
            ),
        RowIdType  = if inRowId<>null then Type.TableColumn(srcType,inRowId) else Any.Type, // Stores Column Typename        
        //< == Variables ===================================================
    
        #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
            Source, 
            inGroupBy, 
                {
                    {"__tmpCount__"     , each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type},
                    {"__MinGroupRowId__", each if  inRowId<> null then List.Min(    Record.Field(_,inRowId) ) else null, RowIdType},
                    {"__AllRows__"      , each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "__outDuplCounter__", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table srcTypeRow}
                }                                           
        ),
        #"Expanded __AllRows__" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "__AllRows__", Columns2Expand),
        nulls4MinRowId = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded __AllRows__",each [__tmpCount__]<=1, null,     
        (currentValue, isConditionTrue, replacementValue) => if isConditionTrue then null else currentValue, // Replace.Value function
        if inRowId<>null then {"__MinGroupRowId__","__outDuplCounter__"} else {"__outDuplCounter__"}
        ),
        
        Add_outDuplInfo = 
            if inRowId<> null then
                Table.AddColumn(nulls4MinRowId, outDuplInfo, 
                    each 
                        if [__outDuplCounter__]=null 
                        then null 
                        else [MinRowId=[__MinGroupRowId__], nDupl = [__outDuplCounter__]] , 
                    type nullable [MinRowId = RowIdType, nDupl = Int64.Type]
                )
            else
                 Table.AddColumn(nulls4MinRowId, outDuplInfo, each [__outDuplCounter__], Int64.Type),
                   
        Result_tfnAddDuplMinRowId = Table.SelectColumns(Add_outDuplInfo, List.Combine({Table.ColumnNames(Source),{outDuplInfo}}))
    in
        Result_tfnAddDuplMinRowId,

    documentation = [
        Documentation.Name =  " tfnAddDuplicatesInfo2 ",
        Documentation.Description     = " Adds two info columns for Duplicates - 1st occurence RowId and given group Occurence Number",
        Documentation.LongDescription = " Adds two info columns for Duplicates - 1st occurence RowId and given group Occurence Number",
        Documentation.Category = " Running Total ",
        Documentation.Source = "  ",
        Documentation.Version = " 1.0 ",
        Documentation.Author = " Denis Sipchenko ",
        Documentation.Examples = {
            [
                Description =  "tfnAddDuplicatesInfo2 arguments: ",
                Code = "
         srcTable    as           table, // input Table
         inGroupBy   as           list,  // List of ColumnNames to search duplicates 
         outDuplInfo as           text,  // Output ColumnName for Information about Duplicates - Duplicate number and Minimal RowId (if inRowId provided) within a group
optional inRowId     as nullable  text   // RowId ColumnName - required for outMinRowId calculation for inGroupBy columns",
                Result =""
            ],
            [
                Description =  "tfnAddDuplicatesInfo2 function call example  ",
                Code = "
let Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText(""hZTBasMwEET/xWdDdteSbP9CT4U2h2JyCK1oQ0xS3IT8frUpWsmSqpxs4ccw2pn1NDXYtA3CBsYNAZE7PNn96cc93+w8n2/uZWwBml07NfwVTIS+nN+PK1SDZzuW1RG7PX3Y5Wb3y4r3uHKHDgrSz9fle7buRQ2e1e5EpuA4sORZw+x/NgIvtnu2jbGP42G5rMS73sMDw0MdlhuODKua68Ai8KT7CH49fH5dVqOOaI6QoO5DCX1PkeraKDTnSKquLdNDjhGLvgMtsE6NZHUKrEnrVBPuU8/F0El6jRykox+UlSR45DCJamEGmODhhpERGNOa5BeNaErrna0NSU3ovpJjXVpqQip1LcGLbZSVJJ1OMLsjBtcm/Y8Ux43BCwcKxa0s0UPqPC84/hV89ws="", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [RowId = Int64.Type, Date = date, Product = _t, Color = _t, Amount = Currency.Type])
in
    tfnAddDuplicatesInfo2(Source,{""Product"",""Color"",""Date""},""DuplInfo"" ,""RowId"")
",
                Result = "Adds to Source table ""DuplInfo"" column with records:
  ""MinRowId"" - Minimal RowId within within given group,
  ""nDupl""    - given group Occurence Number
"
            ],
            [
                Description =  "tfnAddDuplicatesInfo2 function short call example  ",
                Code = "
let Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText(""hZTBasMwEET/xWdDdteSbP9CT4U2h2JyCK1oQ0xS3IT8frUpWsmSqpxs4ccw2pn1NDXYtA3CBsYNAZE7PNn96cc93+w8n2/uZWwBml07NfwVTIS+nN+PK1SDZzuW1RG7PX3Y5Wb3y4r3uHKHDgrSz9fle7buRQ2e1e5EpuA4sORZw+x/NgIvtnu2jbGP42G5rMS73sMDw0MdlhuODKua68Ai8KT7CH49fH5dVqOOaI6QoO5DCX1PkeraKDTnSKquLdNDjhGLvgMtsE6NZHUKrEnrVBPuU8/F0El6jRykox+UlSR45DCJamEGmODhhpERGNOa5BeNaErrna0NSU3ovpJjXVpqQip1LcGLbZSVJJ1OMLsjBtcm/Y8Ux43BCwcKxa0s0UPqPC84/hV89ws="", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [RowId = Int64.Type, Date = date, Product = _t, Color = _t, Amount = Currency.Type])
in
    tfnAddDuplicatesInfo2(Source,{""Product"",""Color"",""Date""},""nDupl"")
",
                Result = "Adds to Source table one column:
  ""nDupl""    - given group Occurence Number
"
            ]
        }
    ]
in  
    Value.ReplaceType(func, Value.ReplaceMetadata(Value.Type(func), documentation))
```

P.S. Idea about *group & expand index column* borrowed from [horseyride](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74718445/6165594) post.

P.S.S. Initially, I took as a source [Running Total by Category by Rick de Groot](https://gorilla.bi/power-query/running-total-by-category/). And than reworked it.

Answer (score 1):

try grouping then expanding in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Product", "Color"}, {
    {"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "nDupl", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table},
    {"MinRowID", each List.Min(_[RowId]), type number}
    }),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"RowId", "Date", "amount", "nDupl"}, {"RowId", "Date", "amount", "nDupl"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Comparing to my solution it's much more compact. But at the same time currently it lacks: 1) function wrap, 2) strict type retaining from original Source Table (RowId is not always number type)

Comment: if RowID is not a number, one could use _[RowId]{0} in place of  List.Min(_[RowId]) and change type number to type text  Feel free to covert to function

Comment: Are you asking and answering your own question at the same time?

Comment: Yes, quite often.  It's one of the approaches suggested by stackoverflow - it's possible to answer before post. Kind of backup - no need to keep and organize solutions somewhere else...

Comment: Can you link me to that suggestion? That is something I had not heard of.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer